# Validation message "Please fill out this field" displaying with <form novalidate>

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms

I'm attempting to create a form with an `<input type="text" />` field where client side validation is disabled with the `novalidate` keyword. Yet when the `Enter` key is pressed the *Please fill out this field* message is still displayed when no input value is provided. When a value is provided, the message is not displayed.

How can the validation message be disabled for simply pressing `Enter` in the input box with no value?

```
class UserSearchForm(Form):

    search = CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['search'].widget.attrs.update({
            "placeholder": "Filter by user",
            "autocomplete": False,
            "required": False,
        })
```

```
  <form id="api_user_search_form" novalidate>
    {% for field in form %}
      {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
  </form>
```

```
let form = document.querySelector("#api_user_search_form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, the [required](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#the-required-attribute) attribute must be present (the field is required) or absent (the field is NOT required). When the attribute is present, it does not matter what value it has.

A [boolean attribute](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) without a value assigned to it (e.g. checked) is implicitly equivalent to one that has the empty string assigned to it (i.e. checked=""). As a consequence, it represents the true value.

The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

I suggest you remove this part in your code.

```
"required": False,
```

Comment: I still had the same problem removing that key/value pair. But with you mentioning that I removed the required attribute with JavaScript and the resolved the problem.